# ansible and continue the script with expect tools

Tags: shell-script, expect, ansible

My expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 1    
spawn /opt/install.sh

expect  "\[input\] Are you installing the application at the central data center? \[yes/no default: yes\]? \[yes\]\r"
send    "yes\r"

expect  "\[input\] What is the code of central data center \[default: 01\]? \[01\]\r"
send    "01\r"

expect  "What is ip or hostname of your server \[default: localhost\]? \[localhost\]\r"
send     "portal\r"

interact

mkdir /opt/dir1
mkdir /opt/dir2
cp /root/file1 /opt/dir1
```

when I run this script by Ansible, after the end of the questions, script stops and won't run another command `mkdir /opt/dir1` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`interact` is an interactive loop that does not exit unless an escape condition is written into it, similar to the `ssh -e escape_char` feature except that you need to write appropriate code to support it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn expect
expect "> "
interact {
  "~" { return }
}
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

which when run:

```
% ./interact
spawn expect
expect1.1> puts hi         # this was typed under interact
hi
expect1.2> exit            # this is where ~ was pressed
%
```